# Function for determining if set of values in 1 binary search tree are equal to another in scheme

Tags: scheme, binary-tree

I'm attempting to write a function that checks if all the values in one binary search tree all appear in another with the function `(bst-set-equal)`, such that `(bst-set-equal? '(1 (5 () (6 () ()))) '(5 (1 () ())(6 () ())))` returns true. However, the function I've written is returning false, and I have been unable to determine why. I hadn't run into any issues with `bst-subset?` when I tested it, but that could very well be the issue, as the setup of `bst-set-equal` seems to make sense.

```
(define (bst-element? item bst-tree)
  (cond ((null? bst-tree)#f)
        ((equal? item (bst-value bst-tree))#t)
        ((bst-element? item (bst-left bst-tree)))
        (else (bst-element? item (bst-right bst-tree)))))

(define (bst-subset? bst1 bst2)
  (cond ((null? bst1)#t)
        ((bst-element? (bst-value bst1)bst2)
         (and (bst-subset? (bst-left bst1)(bst-left bst2))
              (bst-subset? (bst-right bst1)(bst-right bst2))))
        (else #f)))

(define (bst-set-equal? bst1 bst2)
  (cond ((and (bst-subset? bst1 bst2)
              (bst-subset? bst2 bst1))#t)
        (else #f)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the function `bst-subset?`, when the test `(bst-element? (bst-value bst1) bst2)` returns true: you check if the left subtree of `bst1` is contained in the left substree of `bst2`, but it could be contained in the *whole* tree `bst2` (and analogously for the rigth subtrees). Moreover, you do not check for emptyness of `bst2`, which can lead to an error.

You could change the function in this way:

```
(define (bst-subset? bst1 bst2)
  (cond ((null? bst1) #t)
        ((null? bst2) #f)
        (else (and (bst-element? (bst-value bst1) bst2)
                   (bst-subset? (bst-left bst1) bst2)
                   (bst-subset? (bst-right bst1) bst2)))))
```

Note also that you could simplify the definition of `bst-set-equal?` by eliminating the redundant `cond`, in this way:

```
(define (bst-set-equal? bst1 bst2)
  (and (bst-subset? bst1 bst2)
       (bst-subset? bst2 bst1)))
```

and, similarly, you could simplify the definition of `bst-element?` as well, for instance in this way:

```
(define (bst-element? item bst-tree)
  (if (null? bst-tree)
      #f
      (or (= item (bst-value bst-tree))
          (bst-element? item (bst-left bst-tree))
          (bst-element? item (bst-right bst-tree)))))
```